# Why is still changing the var even if the code is done?

Tags: c, variables, printf

Explanation of Code:
My code asks the user a date after the year 2000 and it will keep on asking until the user inputs 0/0/0 as the date. My code should only store the lowest date inputted.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
 int m, d, y, mm, dd, yy, loop = 1, trial = 0;

 while(loop != 0){
  printf("Enter a date (mm/dd/yy): ");

  if(trial == 0){                              //Just to store in value for dd, mm, yy for the first time
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &mm, &dd, &yy);
    if(dd == 0 && mm == 0 && yy == 0){         //If on the first attempt they put in 0/0/0, end the code
      return 0;
    }
    trial++;                                  //To stop this trial
  }
  else{
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &m, &d, &y);            //Hold the new inputted value
  }

  if(d == 0 && m == 0 && y == 0){             //Ending the code after first trial
    printf("%d/%d/%d is the earliest date", mm, dd, yy);
    return 0;
  }

  if(y <= yy){                                //Changing the stored variable 
    yy = y;

    if(m <= mm){
      mm = m;

      if(d <= dd){
        dd = d;
      }
    }
  }
 }

 return 0;
 }
```

I inputted this and I got this as the output:

```
Enter a date (mm/dd/yy):  01/05/06
Enter a date (mm/dd/yy):  0/0/0
1/5/0 is the earliest date
```

For some reason, it's changing the year which I don't want it to do. I was thinking of changing the code so it changes the date into days and then, it will compare it to see what is smaller. I even tried to change up the code, but that didn't work.

Comment: On the first loop iteration, `m,d,y` are uninitialized, and yet you are still comparing them against `mm, dd, yy`

Comment: that's way too complex. No wonder why you get bugs.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your results.  When I take the program as shown, compile it, and give it the same input you did, I get `1/5/6 is the earliest date`. Are you sure you are testing the same program you showed us?

Comment: You can simplify the code substantially if you just initialize the variables to simple values that are not in range, such `mm = 0, dd = 0, yy = 1999`

Comment: yes, i gave the same program. Which program are you using?

Comment: First time `if(y <= yy){` executes, what is `y`?  Does the following `yy = y;` execute?  (Hint: `y` might be 0)

Comment: "My code asks the user a date after the year 2000", Hmmm there is no `2000` in code, so it appears to only ask for a year, of any value.

Comment: Chux, you solved my problem and made me realize I had another problem in the code. You were right about the y = 0.

Comment: You can write that as the answer and I will give it a check mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in the code is that `y` doesn't have a value. Therefore, the code interprets `y` as `y = 0`. Even if you do that, there is still a problem in the code. You are trying to store the lowest date, but the code is only storing the lowest number. Therefore, you should up your code to something like:

```
if(y < yy){ 
    yy = y;
    mm = m;
    dd = d;
  }

  if(y = yy){
    if(m < mm){
      yy = y;
      mm = m;
      dd = d;
    }

    if(m == mm){
      if(d < dd){
        yy = y;
        mm = m;
        dd = d;
      }

      if(d == dd){
        yy = y;
        mm = m;
        dd = d;
      }
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: The y value thing should go to Chux since he/she found it first.